# powershell - capture stdout and stderr to files while also keeping them in the terminal

Tags: powershell, redirect, terminal, stdout, stderr

I have a script which logs via Write-Output and Write-Error, and which calls many other scripts and executables.
When I run it directly, I'm happy with what I see in the terminal.
But I'd like to additionally capture the two streams to two separate files, while maintaining behavior in the terminal.

This comes close, but the terminal doesn't get stderr:

```
& .\main.ps1 2> stderr.log | Tee-Object -FilePath stdout.log
```

I've considered running it as a background task, but I worry that I'd lose the ability to Ctrl-C it easily.  My work will be used by many engineers, so I don't want to introduce unexpected behaviors.

Comment: Since you are already requiring the executors to know the error and out file names, you could just move that functionality to inside of the script. You can have a parameter in the `main.ps1` (call it `errorfile`) for the `stderr.log` filename. In the areas that do `write-error "some error"`, you can just add `$error[0] > $errorfile`. Then your runnable command becomes `& .\main.ps1 stderr.log | Tee-Object -FilePath stdout.log`

Comment: hi, thank you. that makes sense, but unfortunately i need to treat main.ps1 more or less as a black box.  I neglected to mention that main.ps1 is just the tip of a large iceberg of scripts and executables, not all of which I'm able to modify. (edited the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# (Re)create the log files.
New-Item stdout.log, stderr.log -Force

# Merge the error stream (2) into the success stream (1) with 2>&1
# Then use the type of the objects to distinguish between 
# error-stream output (whose objects are of type [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord])
# and success-stream output (all other types).
.\main.ps1 2>&1 | ForEach-Object {
  if ($_ -is [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]) { $_ >> stderr.log }
  else                                                   { $_ >> stdout.log }
  $_ # pass through
}
```

Note: Given that the output files are opened and closed (for appending to via `>>`) *in every iteration*, this solution will be slow.

Answer (score 2):

If you can live with the fact, that both streams land in one file (basically like the view in the terminal), this will do the trick:

```
& .\main.ps1 2>&1 | Tee-Object -FilePath stdout_and_stderr.log
```

It redirects `stderr` to `stdout` and pipes it to `Tee-Object` like before.

Comment: thank you. This is likely what I'll do, altho it's not what I set out to do. The main script I'm running is also run on a service I don't own and which captures the two streams in separate files, and I'd like to emulate that behavior as closely as possible while running on an interactive terminal session. Probably I'll send them both to a single `stdout.txt` file and just write something like "stderr is merged into stdout.txt" into stderr.txt.  Thanks again.